# Hbox "widths" attribute is not set in ZK?

Tags: zk

I have following code,

```
<window  width="200px" title="Box layout" border="normal">
    <hbox spacing="0" width="100%" widths="30%,70%">
        <textbox value="sample" />
        <textbox value="abc" />
    </hbox>
</window>
```

Here am trying to divide two text boxes through widths attribute in ZK. But the width remains same though I have given width for that.

Is correct or how else I can solve this to have same width component in all browers? Please someone help with this.

Comment: I found some solution for the reported question. But inplace="true" attribute not working sometimes while have it in combobox in zk. Even click on many times on component it doesnt become editable. Can anyone please answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hflex` attribute instead of `width` for that.

```xml
<hbox spacing="0" hflex="1">
    <textbox value="sample" hflex="3"/>
    <textbox value="abc"  hflex="7"/>
</hbox>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but while use hflex, sometimes the components wobbles.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width for each textbox.

```
<window  width="200px" title="Box layout" border="normal">
    <hbox spacing="0" widths="70%,30%">
        <textbox value="sample" width="100%" />
        <textbox value="abc" width="100%" />
    </hbox>
</window>
```

[Here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1rnalco/1-Another-new-ZK-fiddle) it works.